# Can a .NET thread be interrupted between a method returning and assigning its return value (without terminating the process)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Is it possible for a .NET thread to somehow stop executing in-between the time a method returns and the time its return value is assigned to a variable/field? Of course, it's possible for the entire process to be terminated or the machine switched off, but is this possible with the process continuing to run?

For example:

```
class Test
{
     public static readonly Mutex MyMutex = new Mutex(false);
     public static bool MutexAcquired = false;

     private static bool AcquireMutex() => MyMutex.WaitOne(1000);

     public static void DoSomething()
     {
         MutexAcquired = AcquireMutex();
     }
}
```

Is it possible that running `DoSomething()` will acquire the mutex (`WaitOne` returns true) but something will interrupt the thread before the value `MutexAcquired` is changed from `false` to `true` (but the process somehow continues running, so something can still read the wrong value of `MutexAcquired`)? Would it be any different if `MutexAcquired` was a local instead of a field?

(I realise that, as written, the `AcquireMutex` method will probably be inlined, but let's assume it's more complex in practice, so it's not inlined.)

Comment: Yes, that's entirely possible. A thread can be interrupted at any time. Only atomic operations can be guaranteed to always execute in full (or not at all).

Comment: The overload of [`Monitor.Enter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=netframework-4.0#System_Threading_Monitor_Enter_System_Object_System_Boolean__) that atomically sets a boolean was added in the .NET 4 timeframe precisely because of the raciness of trying to assign *after* the method returns. (In rare cases before that, `lock`, which uses `Monitor`, could leak the lock)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is entirely possible.  Assignments are not guaranteed to be atomic, and the thread can be interrupted at any time (no one can tell when its quantum will expire, or a higher priority thread will have to be scheduled).

Then, you also need to consider that the Commpiler or CPU can optimize your code to make it even less thread-safe.  Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx).

If `MutexAcquired` is a local variable, it will be accessible only by the current thread so no locking will be required.  Locking / atomic operations is necessary only when data is accessed by multiple threads.